# preg_replace double replacement

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm getting some unexpected results from a regular expression, which is meant to be replacing the classname on a namespace. The replacement appears to happen twice, so that the classname getting replaced is duplicated (see example below).

I've actually resolved the problem by changing the reg ex to match 1 or more (`+`) rather than 0 or more (`*`) which is actually more accurate for what I want.

However, I'm a little confused as to why I was getting an issue in the first place.

Here is an example of the problem:

```
$classns  = 'components\groups\GroupsController';
$newclass = 'GroupsAccess';
$classns = preg_replace('/[^\\\\]*$/', $newclass, $classns);
echo $classns;
```

Result

```
components\groups\GroupsAccessGroupsAccess
```

Expected

```
components\groups\GroupsAccess
```

Is it possible that the * is matching a word boundary or something of that nature?

The confusing part for me is that a preg_match using the same regex shows only one result, so it would appear to be something specific to how preg_match runs the regex.

e.g.

```
preg_match('/[^\\\\]*$/', $classns, $m);
var_dump($m);
```

Result

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "GroupsAccess" }
```

Comment: what does `preg_match_all` show? `preg_match` _always_ shows at most one match.

Comment: @JanDvorak Good catch. It shows two matches.

Comment: Why aren't you just using str_replace here?

Comment: @JohnKugelman The trick is `[...]*$` can match the end-of-line alone. Hard to tell why it _does_ continue once it's at the end, though.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak - Thanks, Oddly, I've tried using trim, to no effect. Is it matching the actual end-boundary?

Comment: @PaulS it is. It can match an empty string as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*` is not matching a word boundary, it is matching **the empty string**.

Your expression is at first matching

> components\groups\ **GroupsController**

and the `$` is an anchor that is matching a position and that is before the end of the string (or a `\n` before the end of the string).

So after the first match the position of the regex parser is after the last "r" and before the end of the string, when it tries to match your regex again. And it will find one more match ==> 0 occurrences of the `/` (the empty string) followed by the end of the string.

Then it moves on, recognize the end of the string and finishes.

Comment: I kinda missed the "Then it moves on" part (if the match is empty, the pointer is advanced by one more character). Now it makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Comment: [`After the first match is found, the subsequent searches are continued on from end of the last match.`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) Are empty matches an exception or I've misunderstood?

Comment: @JanDvorak, what is an "empty match"? It matches because the defined pattern is found(of course it is an empty string). The regex engine will always continue the search after the last found match.

Comment: An empty match = match that ends where it starts (only lookaround and boundaries). Then, according to the previous sentence, the next match should start at the same place as this one (and cause the match to be repeated infinitely).

Comment: @JanDvorak, no in such a case the regex engine will move the current position, otherwise it would match here in an endless loop.

Comment: Then it seems the documentation for `preg_match_all` is incorrect/incomplete, as it does not mention this (perfectly expectable) behavior but rather indicates that the infinite loop should happen instead. Not that bad documentation would be surprising in PHP, though.

Answer (score 2):

Narrowing it down, this also shows two matches:

```
preg_match_all('/a*$/', 'a', $m);`
```

Python has the same behavior:

```
>>> re.findall('a*$', 'a')
['a', '']
```

So does Perl:

```
>>> my @m = 'a' =~ /a*$/g;
>>> foreach (@m) { print "$_\n"; }
a
<blank>
```

It appears that the regex engines match both `'a'` and the empty string `''` that follows it. Technically this is correct, although it is surprising. `'a'` is a string that is anchored at the end of the search string, and so is `''`.

One basic rule of matching is that matches don't overlap. Once a match has been found the regex engine continues searching for the next match at end of the previous match. What I didn't expect is that the anchor `$` can be re-used, presumably since it is a zero-width assertion and not an actual substring match.