# How to use preg_replace regardless of the input?

Tags: php, regex

I have an input field in which users can specify a pattern for replacements.

But I want to allow them to leave it empty, and treat it like "pattern can be anything". Please remember the string ($subject) can be empty or not empty!

I tried using ".*" for this but it writes a double output. What can I use instead?

An empty pattern is just one of many possible patterns so I prefer to have a regex for it even though I can just do `if (empty($pattern)) echo $replacement;`.

```
<?php

echo '<ol>';
echo '<li><ol>';
    
$pattern = '';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = 'Foo bar';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

$pattern = '';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = '';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

echo '</ol><li><ol>';

$pattern = '';
if (empty($pattern))
    $pattern = '.*';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = 'Foo bar';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

$pattern = '';
if (empty($pattern))
    $pattern = '.*';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = '';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

echo '</ol><li><ol>';

$pattern = '';
if (empty($pattern))
    $pattern = '.+';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = 'Foo bar';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

$pattern = '';
if (empty($pattern))
    $pattern = '.+';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = '';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

echo '</ol><li><ol>';

$pattern = '';
if (empty($pattern))
    $pattern = '$^';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = 'Foo bar';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

$pattern = '';
if (empty($pattern))
    $pattern = '$^';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = '';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

echo '</ol><li><ol>';

$pattern = '';
if (empty($pattern))
    $pattern = '(?:)';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = 'Foo bar';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

$pattern = '';
if (empty($pattern))
    $pattern = '(?:)';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = '';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

echo '</ol><li><ol>';

$pattern = '';
if (empty($pattern))
    $pattern = '(?=a)o';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = 'Foo bar';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

$pattern = '';
if (empty($pattern))
    $pattern = '(?=a)o';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = '';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

echo '</ol><li><ol>';

$pattern = '';
if (empty($pattern))
    $pattern = '.\A';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = 'Foo bar';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

$pattern = '';
if (empty($pattern))
    $pattern = '.\A';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = '';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

echo '</ol><li><ol>';

$pattern = '';
if (empty($pattern))
    $pattern = '\z.';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = 'Foo bar';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

$pattern = '';
if (empty($pattern))
    $pattern = '\z.';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = '';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

echo '</ol><li><ol>';

$pattern = '';
if (empty($pattern))
    $pattern = '(?!)';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = 'Foo bar';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

$pattern = '';
if (empty($pattern))
    $pattern = '(?!)';
$replacement = 'Sample output';
$subject = '';
echo '<li>' . preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replacement, $subject);

?>
```

The needed output (for empty and non empty strings) should be:

1. Sample Output
2. Sample Output

As you can see below, the output is never like that:

1. 1. Sample outputFSample outputoSample outputoSample output Sample outputbSample outputaSample outputrSample output
   2. Sample output
2. 1. Sample outputSample output
   2. Sample output
3. 1. Sample output
   2. 
4. 1. Foo bar
   2. Sample output
5. 1. Sample outputFSample outputoSample outputoSample output Sample outputbSample outputaSample outputrSample output
   2. Sample output
6. 1. Foo bar
   2. 
7. 1. Foo bar
   2. 
8. 1. Foo bar
   2. 
9. 1. Foo bar
   2. 

Comment: Use `.+` instead.

Comment: Use `/$^/` as regex which would always fail and you will get original input back

Comment: Also if pattern is empty - just return replacement, no?

Comment: As it has been pointed out, you need to use any regex that will never match any string, like `(?=a)o`, `$^`, `.\A`, `\z.`, `(?!)`, etc.

Comment: I've added all of these possible solutions to show you they don't cover both situations - empty and not empty strings - and for @Wiktor Stribiżew don't cover either situation.

Comment: If you need to *match* any 0 or more chars, use `'/\A.*\z/s'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your new comment did the trick! Although this made me realize `^.*$` (you'd probably say `/^.*$/s`) works the same. If some people care to vote to reopen this question, we could have an answer to it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replacement gets doubled because `preg_replace` replaces all match occurrences in the string, and `.*` pattern is capable of matching empty strings, and it does match the whole string first, and then - it is PCRE feature - allows the next match right at the end of the string. See [preg_replace double replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705170/preg-replace-double-replacement).

In your case, the solution is using *both* start of string (`^` or `\A`) *and* end of string (`$` or `\z`) anchors:

```
'/\A.*\z/s'
'/^.*$/s'
```

This way, you will always match a string, be it empty or not, once.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! But why did they remove points from both **you** and I? Also, what made you think of \A and \z and not just the standard ^ and $?

Comment: @LWC `\A` in the case above is the same as `^`, and `$` will work as `\z`, too, because `.*` is greedy and matches any chars. Just `\A` and `\z` always mean the same, the start of string and the very end of string correspondingly. I like monosemantic patterns, their behavior cannot be redefined. `$` is not equal to `\z` even when `m` flag is not used, but this is not relevant here, so both will work.

Comment: Vote done, please consider doing the same for the question. But like you asked, why would people downvote an accepted answer? This answer really helped me, so it would be a shame to remove this question because of this craziness.